# Destructor gives output I don't understand (Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop):)

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

We've been asked to write a class for matrices, and so far I have the following:

[Code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7073505/)

But we're supposed to: "implement the following member functions: Parameterized constructor (utilizing new) and destructor (utilizing delete)"

And I'm not sure quite what that means but I think I've done that. The problem is when I uncomment line 65, I get a strange runtime error that I've not seen before. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks :)

Edit:
Who voted my question down and why?

Also, I added:

```
        matrix(matrix &m) {
        // Copy size and declare new array
        mdata=0; size=(m.getcols()*m.getrows());
        if(size>0) {
            mdata=new double[size];
            // Copy values into new array
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
                mdata[i] = m.mdata[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
delete [] mdata;
```

and the error has gone now, so thank you Ilya Kobelevskiy and aruisdante for your answers.

Comment: Try using `delete[] mdata` instead of `delete mdata`. Using `delete mdata` results in undefined behaviour in this case as you allocated the memory with `new[]` (not `new`).

Comment: `double free` means you're using delete piece of data (i.e. deleting something twice). Also, if you're deleting an array you need to use `delete[]` instead. Just my $0.02.

Comment: The copy constructor you added should be `matrix(const matrix&)`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Oh yes, good spot. Do you know why my assignment operator isn't working? New code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7074562/

Comment: The destructor is called on whatever I've just assigned a value to as soon as the assignment is done, I think. Not sure why it goes out of scope. I don't really understand this yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not implement a copy constructor, so default one is called when you return by value from multiplication function.

Default constructor simply copies members byte-wise, so you end up having two matrices containing mdata that is pointing to the same memory block. When destructor for second matrix is called, it is trying to free memory that was already freed, hence the error.

Of course, plus what other people pointed out about delete [].

In general, you should follow [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29). Applied to your case, it would mean that if you do anything non-trivial in destructor, you should either explicitly implement assignment operator and copy constructor, or declare them private and not implement them to avoid automatic compiler generated ones and make class non-copyable.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete an array, you need to use the [`delete[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/) operator rather than the `delete` one. Note that deleting an array via `delete` is actually undefined behavior, that just happens to be what your particular code combination and compiler seem to be doing.

Comment: _"When you use simply delete on an array, it's trying to free the memory for pointer itself, rather than what the pointer is pointing to"_  Not true

Comment: For some reason I still get the same error, but only when the multiplication function is run. If it isn't run, there's no error.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I don't know if you missed my edit, but I updated to reflect that this just happens to be how his particular compiler/code combination is resolving the undefined behavior.

Comment: You're getting the double-free error with multiplication because you're returning a shallow copy, which means that the backing array pointers point to the same location. However, when you leave the scope of the multiplication function, the `product` matrix is deleted, freeing the backing array. And then when the returned result is deleted, it's trying to free memory that's already freed. You need to implemented a proper copy constructor/`operator=` that does a deep copy.

Comment: I saw it, but it's still not true. The compiler is not "freeing the memory for the pointer itself".

Comment: I'm not expressing myself clearly, so I've just deleted the relevant part of the answer so that it doesn't confuse anyone that bothers to read all of the answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

mdata is an array, when you delete it in destructor, you need to add []:

```
delete [] mdata;
```